# What kind of hardware multiplier do modern processors use?

Tags: fpga, verilog, cpu, computer-architecture, multiplier

I was wondering what kind of multiplier implementations modern processors use. Is it some derived variant of booth Wallace tree algorithm? Are these kinds of micro-architectural details publicized nowadays? What about back in the late 90's or early 2000's? Would a booth Wallace tree perform well on an FPGA? I'd imagine the Wallace tree aspect would cause some problems.

Comment: Some architectures have a multiplication instruction that is considered a pseudo instruction and is typically executed by recursive binary addition.

Comment: I see. That makes sense to me for integer multiplies. Just break the instruction down into micro-ops. It would also benefit from the core having multiple functional units I suppose. What about floating point data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FPGAs have hardware multipliers on them these days (for example, the DSP48 MAC block in Xilinx architectures.)

That said, it probably depends on the size of the MPY. Back when I was working on this stuff (1980s, at Weitek) modified Booth's algorithm was all the rage for 16, 32 and 64-bit sizes. Now? Not sure. Since then there's the Carry-save architecture and other proposals. It's probably secret sauce beyond that.